# How do I run an Excel formula in one cell (have it produce a value) ONLY if another cell's formula produces a value?

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, conditional-statements

I want to run this Excel formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Y163:AA163,MATCH(TRUE,Y163:AA163<>"",0)),"")
```

But ONLY if the formula in cell B163 produces a result/value.

I've tried different formulas but cell X163 still produces a value even though B163's formula has not produced a value.

Example formulas I've tried:

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEN(B163)<>"",(INDEX(Y163:AA163,MATCH(TRUE,Y163:AA163<>"",0)),""),"")
```

```
=IFERROR(IF(B163<>0,(INDEX(Y163:AA163,MATCH(TRUE,Y163:AA163<>"",0)),""),"")
```

In other words, I want a formula in X163 that states that if B163's formula results in a value or is not equal to 0, then run the formula beginning with "INDEX." On top of this, put this all in an IFERROR statement, because that's what I do with all my formulas. So there are a lot of nested formulas/statements.

How can I get this new condition to override other conditions?

Comment: `=IFERROR(IF(B163<>"",...` Len returns a number and it will never match `""`.  If that does not work, please post the formula in B163.

Comment: As @Scott Craner said, `LEN` returns a number. I always use `IF(LEN(A1 > 0), ...`. Try `=IFERROR(IF(LEN(B163)>0,(INDEX(Y163:AA163,MATCH(TRUE,Y163:AA163<>"",0)),""),"")`

Comment: Neither worked, unfortunately

Comment: What is the formula in B163?

Comment: =IFERROR(INDEX(Y163:AA163,MATCH(TRUE,Y163:AA163<>"",0)),"")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These formulas worked:

```
=IFERROR(IF(B163>0,INDEX(Y163:AA163,MATCH(TRUE,Y163:AA163<>"",0)),""),"")
```

...or

```
=IFERROR(IF([@Total]>0,INDEX(Y163:AA163,MATCH(TRUE,Y163:AA163<>"",0)),""),"")
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `IFERROR` in your second formula.

Based on your description use:
`IF(OR(B163<>0,B163<>""),INDEX(Y163:AA163,MATCH(TRUE,Y163:AA163<>"",0)),"")`

Comment: Thank you, though it still produces the result of the Index formula, ignoring the condition of B163.

Comment: What is the result of B163 when it does? (I changed the condition for the value being not equal to 0 instead of being equal to. I misread the question.

Comment: This worked!: =IFERROR(IF([@Total]>0,INDEX(Y163:AA163,MATCH(TRUE,Y163:AA163<>"",0)),""),"")